# How to move selected lines (up / down) in VIM for VSCode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I use this settings on my json

```json
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["J"],
        "commands": ["editor.action.moveLinesDownAction"]
    }, // moveLineDown
    {
        "before": ["K"],
        "commands": ["editor.action.moveLinesUpAction"]
    } // moveLineUp
],
```

But this just move the current line. What I want is when I select many lines with `shift + v` I can move those lines up and down?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing for visual mode in your vscode settings

```
"vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
{
  "before": [
    "J"
  ],
  "commands": [
    "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction"
  ]
},
{
  "before": [
    "K"
  ],
  "commands": [
    "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction"
  ]
}
]
```